# Dependency issues migrating project from ASP.NET 5 RC1 to ASP.NET Core 1.0

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, dnx, .net-core, .net-core-rc2

I am having a hard time converting my asp.net (core) app from **dnx46** to **.netcoreapp1.0** because of two particular dependencies ( *Microsoft.Azure.ServiceBus* and *System.IO.Ports.SerialPort* )

Being positive, I'm making the bet that these feature will eventually land on .net core one day.. but in the meantime, I found that converting my app from moniker **dnx46** to **.netstandard1.3** allows me to resolve the ServiceBus dependency.

Resolving *System.IO.Ports.SerialPort* however is still an issue and I don't understand how to make this work. I was hoping that importing **net462** framework in .netstandard1.3 moniker, would allow to find the System.IO.Ports.SerialPort object but it does not.

What am I missing ?

For reference, there's my project.json :

```
{
  "dependencies": {
    "Microsoft.NETCore.App": {
      "version": "1.0.0-rc2-3002702",
      "type": "platform"
    },
    "Microsoft.NETCore.Platforms": "1.0.1-*",
    "Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore": "1.0.0-rc2-final",
    "Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Sqlite": "1.0.0-rc2-final",
    [...more stuff...]
  },
  "frameworks": {
    "netcoreapp1.0": {
      "dependencies": {
        // To be restored when they'll become available on .net core
        //  "Microsoft.WindowsAzure.ConfigurationManager": "3.2.1",
        //  "WindowsAzure.ServiceBus": "3.2.1",
      }
    },
    "netstandard1.3": {
      "buildOptions": {
        "define": [ "INCLUDE_WINDOWSAZURE_FEATURE" ]
      },
      // Imports of net462 fixes loading of
      //  - NewtonSoft.Json
      //  - System.Runtime.Loader for "Microsoft.NETCore.App"
      "imports": [
        "net462"
      ],
      "dependencies": {
        "Microsoft.NETCore.Portable.Compatibility": "1.0.1-rc2-24027"
        "Microsoft.WindowsAzure.ConfigurationManager": "3.2.1",
        "WindowsAzure.ServiceBus": "3.2.1",
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Resolving System.IO.Ports.SerialPort however is still an issue and I don't understand how to make this work. I was hoping that importing net462 framework in .netstandard1.3 moniker, would allow to find the System.IO.Ports.SerialPort object but it does not.

You can't reference `System.IO.Ports.SerialPort` when targeting .NET Core or .NET Standard, because this contract only exists in the full .NET Desktop framework.

This library might be eventually [ported](https://github.com/dotnet/corefx/issues/984) but in the meantime, you'll have to use .NET Desktop (e.g `net462`) instead of .NET Core.

Remove `netcoreapp1.0` and `netstandard1.3` and add `net462` and it should work.

Comment: I actually didn't realize I could do the contrary : Have a `net462` framework section and do an import on `netcoreapp1.0` to get all the `AspNetCore` and `EntityFrameworkCore` functionalities.

Comment: You don't need to import `netcoreapp1.0` for `net462` because both ASP.NET Core and EF Core are compatible with .NET Desktop (importing `netcoreapp1.0` for `net462` doesn't make much sense, anyway)

Comment: Gotcha, you are right.Recent renaming and re-versioning storm got the best of me I'm afraid :/ I was convinced that EF*Core* and asp.net *core* both required .net*core* to run which isn't the case.. So confusing at first. If I may ask, what's the purpose and when's right time to use the import section ?

Answer (score 2):

If you plan on deploying to a windows box and targeting `net452`, then simply take on a dependency on `net452`. I put together a [migration guide](https://ievangelist.github.io/blog/migrating-to-rc2/) to share my upgrading experiences, perhaps it might help? I initially had this misunderstanding that I would take a dependency of `netstandard1.*` and then `"import": "net4*"`, David Fowler laughed at me and said something to the extent of "dude that's do wrong!". :P

You should change your `project.json frameworks` to look like this:

```
"frameworks": {
    "net462": { }
  }
```

Comment: Ideally I would like to have the app deploy-able on any box supported by .net core ( So not specially a Windows box ). Targeting net46* feels like a fallback plan after all the advertising on .net core benefits I told to the customer. I followed Pinpoint's and your suggestion importing the `netcoreapp1.0` to the `net462` framework and the app now compiles. Since you had a chat with David Fowler on this `import / dependency` concept, do you have a clearer idea on what import does ? ( talking about this import -> `framework : { import : [] }` )